# ImageMagick: annotateImage line height?

Tags: php, imagemagick

Does anyone know if it is possible to set the line height of text written with annotateImage? I am writing a single line of text on an image and the bottoms of "p" & "g" are getting cut off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to wrap text in imagemagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577870/how-to-wrap-text-in-imagemagick)

Comment: Can you post an example of what exactly you are doing, which parameters you use, etc.?

Answer (score 10):

Try interline spacing:

`convert -interline-spacing 20   label:'First\nSecond'  label_lspace_20.gif`

PHP: `$draw->setTextInterlineSpacing(20);`

See: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#interline-spacing